# send an integer value of a variable from javascript to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

HTML CODE

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="quantity" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var qty=10;
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $("#quantity").val(qty);
});
```

PHP FILE (send.php)

```
<?php
$showqty=$_POST['qty'];
echo $showqty;
?>
```

My code above is receiving an error on the php file. It says that the index qty is undefined. How can I send an integer value of a variable from javascript to php?

Comment: added the jQuery tag, as jQuery and Javascript are not identical and u are using jQuery syntax.

Comment: Im actually using Jquery for this project.

Comment: thank u for identifying what i already had identified. i was adding jQuery to the tags because you had not, and if u want people to assist you then using the appropriate tags will recruit targeted assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have any issues with you `javascript` or you `PHP` code.

when you recieve *undefined* error, it means that the object is not even posted to the *send.php* file. so the problem is with the object or the way you are sending it, not with the value in it.

with a look at you code I saw that you have two `action` tags and no `method` tag and that is what causing the error.

with no method tag, the form uses `GET` method instead of `POST` method.

so you just have to change this line:

```
<form action="send.php" action="post">
```

with this line:

```
<form action="send.php" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use

`var qty = document.getElementById("qty").value`

Comment: Not really. The OP is trying to do the exact opposite thing.

Answer (score 0):

`action="post">` should be `method="post">`

This may help you:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var qty=10;
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    var qty=10;
    $.ajax({
        url:'send.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{'qty':qty},
        success: function(e){
            alert(e);
            //do some thing
            }
        });

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="send.php" method="post" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

send.php

```
<?php
$showqty=$_POST['qty'];
echo $showqty;
?>
```